# Why does Term::ReadLine work for gcc4 compiled per but not gcc6?

Tags: perl

I just noticed that the functionality of Term::ReadLine has changed (for the worse) after upgrading from a gcc4 compiled version of perl to a gcc6 compiled version. With gcc4, the backspace key was interpreted correctly, allowing the user to edit the line he/she was entering. The gcc6 version apparently does not, returning a ^? every time the backspace key is entered.

Here's some simple code I used to test this...

```
#!/tool/pandora64/.package/perl-5.24.0-gcc620/bin/perl5.24.0
#/tool/pandora64/.package/perl-5.24.0/bin/perl5.24.0

use strict;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $answer;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('EDIT_STDIN');
$term->ornaments(0);
$answer = $term->readline("Enter something here....");

print "answer: $answer\n";

exit;
```

As it is, this script fails to interpret the backspace key correctly as described above.  Swap lines 1 and 2 and it works fine.

Sooooo..... any ideas why this is happening?  Any suggestions on how to get this to work given that I can't go back to gcc4 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your compiler, and everything to do with your `TERM` environment variable and OS configuration and readline library. Something almost certainly changed there too.

Comment: What's the value of `$term->ReadLine` under both versions of perl? (Case matters here!)

Comment: If the question's claim is accurate, that swapping the shebang lines is all it takes to switch between correct and incorrect behaviors, then that rather strongly implies that the environment (including `$TERM`) and OS configuration are identical in both cases. Might be linking to a different readline lib, though.

Comment: I think you may have hit something Dave with the val of $term->ReadLine...
For the version that works, it's...   "Term::ReadLine::Gnu" .                              
For the version that fails, it's......    "Term::ReadLine::Stub" .                              
"Stub" ?  What's going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the problem was that Term::ReadLine::Gnu was missing for Perl 5.24.0-gcc620 .  After installed, it runs fine.